# An example of square matrix which satisfy two conditions

Tags: linear-algebra

Give an example of square matrix which:

1. Have two (and no more, only two!) eigen values: $0$ and $1$.
2. $0$ and $1$ are once eigen values.

I have a big problem with this task, because I can't construct diagonal matrix $D$:

if I will, I have $A = PDP^{-1}$ but it is impossible because $D= \begin{bmatrix} d_1&0&0\\0&d_2&0\\0&0&d_3\end{bmatrix}$ where $d_1,d_2,d_3$ are eigen values. I have only two, so I can't construct this matrix.

Do you have any idea? Im so confused...

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your conditions. Are you saying that $0$ and $1$ are the only eigenvalues? Or are you saying that it must have eigenvalues $0$ and $1$, and their arithmetic multiplicity can only be $1$? If it's the former, the matrix must be $2\times{2}$.

Comment: Their arithmetic multiplicity can only be 1. I forgot, that in contents this task write: Give an example of square matrix $ 3 \times 3$. So do you think that is mistake and should be $2 \times 2$?

Comment: So in other words, it must be a $3\times{3}$ matrix, have one eigenvalue equal to $0$, one equal to $1$, and the third eigenvalue can be any number?

Answer (score 1):

Take an arbitrary non-singular $2\times{2}$ matrix $P$, and make $D$ a $2\times{2}$ diagonal matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

or

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Note that $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$ are themselves examples of square matrices which satisfy your two conditions.

Answer (score 0):

The question may have to do with the distinction between [algebraic and geometric multiplicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Algebraic_multiplicities) of eigenvalues.

Certainly a square matrix of size $\gt 2$ may have eigenvalues $0$ and $1$ only, with geometric multiplicities one, but algebraic multiplicities as large as needed to account for the matrix size.

In particular here is such a $5\times 5$ matrix:

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$

with geometric multiplicity one for both eigenvalues $0$ and $1$.

Note that such matrices are *not* diagonal, thus avoiding the problem that the OP seems to have in constructing an example.